# Calculating area of fitted function to compare with results - Mathematica

Tags: 3d, compare, wolfram-mathematica, areas

H! 
 I've spent a lot of time reading Mathematica's Document Center and stackoverflow (among other sites), but I haven't found any answer to my question: How in Mathematica I can compare areas (quantitatively) of function (to be precise - results) and its fit. I'd like to get some numerical estimation of my fit. The function of course is in 3D.
Cheers, 
     John

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by 'area of a function'. do you have an example?

Comment: I mean an area under the function - it's a practical question, meaning I need that answer to proceed with my analysis. Though I don't know how could I present that example here...

Comment: have you looked at `Integrate` or `NIntegrate`?

Comment: Yes - that would be a normal approach. The problem nevertheless lays within my results, they're in discrete form and I don't know how to calculate an area under my points (results).

Comment: You can use `Interpolation` to make a continuous function from discrete data points and `NIntegrate` that.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the data you're working with?

Comment: Might check possibilities of LinearModelFit and NonlinearModelFit. Also the result of FindFit can be used to sum norms of residuals (I assume it is a measure of the residuals you want, when referring to the "area"). Would be easier to say someting concrete if you provide a specific example of input and desired output.

Comment: For a 2D plot I would know how to interpret the concept of an area between dataplot and its fit, but for a 3D plot I'd say you'd need volume and not area. If you want to determine goodness of fit you better look  for a specific text like the chi-squared test (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit)

Answer (score 1):

If the actual goal is to estimate how good your fit is, then you do not need to calculate any "areas" - Mathematica has built in analysis offered by LinearModelFit[...] and NonlinearModelFit[...]. Let's make up some dataset scattered around a Gaussian surface:

```
data = MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]], 
 1.2 Exp[-34 ((#1 - .56).(#1 - .56))] + #2} &, {RandomReal[
 1, {100, 2}], RandomReal[{-.1, .1}, 100]}];
```

Introduce a Gaussian surface model to fit these data:

```
model = a Exp[-b ((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2)];
```

Now, do the nonlinear regression:

```
    nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   model, {a, b, {x0, .5}, {y0, .6}}, {x, y}];
```

Obtain and plot the best fit:

```
    Show[Plot3D[nlm["BestFit"], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5], Mesh -> 25], 
 ListPointPlot3D[data, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red]]]
```

[image: Plot]

The function nlm[…] contains a lot of information:

```
nlm["Properties"]
```

[image: Properties]

Here are few properties relevant to your request:

```
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter Table]

```
nlm["ANOVATable"]
```

[image: ANOVA Table]

Thanks,
Vitaliy